# Find the roots of the polynomial $x^3-2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Find the roots of the polynomial $x^3-2$.

If $\alpha$ be the root of this polynomial i.e., $\alpha^3=2$,
then $(\zeta \alpha)^3=2$, where $\zeta$ is $3^{rd}$ root of unity.

Hence the solutions of this equations are
$$\zeta{2}^\frac{1}{3}$$,  $\zeta$ a $p^{th}$ root of unity
And we know that $\zeta_n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$

So the roots are $2^\frac{1}{3}, -(2^\frac{1}{3}) ~and~ 2^\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}i-1).$

Is this correct?

*Note: I don't like factoring method. I studied in schools time. So don't help with that method.*

Thanks!

Comment: There is a typo somewhere, either $x^3 - 3$ or $\alpha^3 = 2$. Also, one of $1,-1, \frac12 (\sqrt3i-1)$ is not a cube root of unity.

Comment: Yeah, There was a typo. Now corrected.

Comment: $-2^{1/3}$ can't be correct, its cube is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $a > 0$ is a real number.

The roots of $x^3 = a$ are these

$x_1 = a^\frac{1}{3} ( \cos{2\pi/3} + i \cdot \sin{2\pi/3} )$
$x_2 = a^\frac{1}{3} ( \cos{4\pi/3} + i \cdot \sin{4\pi/3} )$
$x_3 = a^\frac{1}{3} ( \cos{6\pi/3} + i \cdot \sin{6\pi/3} )$

We can simplify these formulas further...

The root $x_3$ happens to be real.
The other two are complex conjugated to each other.

Seems your problem is that your knowledge of the roots of unity is a bit rusty.

You can refresh it here:

[Roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)

Once you know how to find the roots of $x^3=1$,
what's left to do is just to add a factor of $a^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: Shouldn't they be $2\pi/3$, $4\pi/3$ and $2\pi$?

Comment: @Student; I think so.

Comment: @Student1058 Yeah, I was solving the wrong equation ( $... = -1$ )

Comment: ohhh, I calculated wronly. Otherwise I was on the right track.

Comment: @Joseph Yeah... you just made some simple mistake, there's nothing complicated here.

Comment: @Student1058 Initially I was solving the wrong equation ( $x^3 = -a$ ) In that case the angles are: $\pi/3, 3\pi/3, 5\pi/3$

Comment: @peter.petrov I see. Understandable. +1.

Answer (score 1):

The **best** way to do it is to use the methods that other responses have detailed.  I am going to show you an **inferior** method only because understanding the relationship between this inferior method and the *better* method (already described by others) will **stretch your intuition.**

Let $a$ denote $2^{(1/3)}.$

Given $0 = (x^3 - 2) = (x^3 - a^3) = (x - a)(x^2 + ax + a^2)$, then

one of the roots will be given by the factor $(x - a)$.

The other two roots will come from applying the quadratic eqn against $(x^2 + ax + a^2) = 0$.

This gives $$x = \frac{1}{2} \times \left[-a \pm\sqrt{a^2 - 4a^2}\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{2} \times \left[-a \pm i \times \sqrt{3} \times a\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{2} \times a \times \left[-1 \pm i \times \sqrt{3}\right]$$

$$= 2^{(1/3)} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \left[-1 \pm i \times \sqrt{3}\right].$$

Comment: I already mentioned I don't like this method.

Comment: @Joseph Very good point.  I was careless in not noticing that you had written that.  Also, I personally do **not** like this method.  Remembering that I **overlooked** what you had written about this, the point of this answer was **not** to advocate a method that I consider **inferior**.  Instead, the point was to stretch intuition by showing the association between this inferior method and the better method already provided by others on this webpage.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. $-(2^{\frac13})$ is not a root of $x^3 - 2$. Instead, the other root is $\zeta_3^2 2^{\frac13}$, which is the complex conjugate of the other complex root.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ be the root of this polynomial i.e., $\alpha^3=2$,
then $(\zeta \alpha)^3=2$, where $\zeta$ is $3^{rd}$ root of unity.

Hence the solutions of this equations are
$$\zeta{2}^\frac{1}{3}$$,  $\zeta$ a $p^{th}$ root of unity
And we know that $\zeta_n=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$

So the roots are

$$x_1=(2)^\frac{1}{3} e^\frac{2\pi .1}{3}=(2)^\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}i-1),$$

$$x_3=(2)^\frac{1}{3} e^\frac{2\pi .2}{3}=(2)^\frac{1}{3},$$

$$x_2=(2)^\frac{1}{3} e^\frac{2\pi .2}{3}=
(2)^\frac{1}{3}(-\frac{1}{2})(\sqrt{3}i+1).$$

Comment: You have written that $e^{\frac{2\pi 2}{3}}\ne e^{\frac{2\pi 2}{3}}$. The roots of unity are not $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$, they are $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Forward**

i) [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$

ii) [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula): $\left(\cos x+i\sin x\right)^n=\cos (nx) + i\sin (nx)$

**Theorem**

If $z\ne 0$, and if $n$ is a positive integer, then there are exactly $n$ distinct complex numbers $z_0,z_1,\dots,z_{n-1}$ such that $z_k^n=z$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$. These roots are given by the formula:
$$z_k=\lvert{z}\rvert^{\frac1n}\exp\left[ i\left(\frac{\text{arg}(z)}{n}+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right],\qquad k=0,\dots,n-1$$
(e.g. Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis*, Theorem 1.51)

**Roots of unity**

Since $\lvert 1\rvert=1$ and $\text{arg}(1)=0$, the $n$ roots of unity are:
\begin{align*}z_k&=1^{\frac1n}\exp\left[i\left(\frac{\text{arg}(z)}{n}+\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\right]=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)\\&=\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}\end{align*}
When $n=3$, the three roots of unity are:
i) $k=0$: $$z_0=\cos 0+i\sin 0=1$$and $1^3=1$;
ii) $k=1$: $$z_1=\cos \frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$and $\left(\cos \frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)^3=\cos (2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi)=1$;
iii) $k=2$: $$z_2=\cos \frac{4\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}=\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$and $\left(\cos \frac{4\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)^3=\cos (4\pi)+i\sin(4\pi)=1$.

**Roots of a real positive number**

If $x^3=2$, then the three roots are:
$$x_0=2^\frac13,\quad x_1=2^\frac13\left(\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right),\quad x_2=2^\frac13\left(\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$